# Question about linear transformations: example of strict content

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear transformation $f:U \rightarrow V$, if $V_1$, $V_2$ are subspaces of V, we know that 
$$f^{-1}(V_1)+f^{-1}(V_2) \subseteq f^{-1}(V_1+V_2).$$

My question is: how to find an example of strict content in the formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to make this work is to take $V_1,V_2$ intersecting $\operatorname{im}(f)$ only at $0$, but such that their sum intersects $\operatorname{im}(f)$ non-trivially. For example, take
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to \Bbb R^2:x\mapsto (x,x)$$
$V_1=\{(x,0)|x\in \Bbb R\}$ and $V_2=\{(0,x)|x\in \Bbb R\}$. Then
$$f^{-1}(V_1)=\{0\}=f^{-1}(V_2),$$
but
$$f^{-1}(V_1+V_2)=f^{-1}(\Bbb R^2)=\Bbb R.$$