# Is the category of f.d. vector spaces coherent?

Tags: category-theory

Let $k$ be a field and write $V$ for the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces over $k$.

It seems to me that all Requirement for a coherent category (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+category) are satisfied for $V$. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the fact that pulling back subspaces does not preserve the sum (which is the join of subobjects in the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces over $k$). I've given a counterexample [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032754/question-about-linear-transformations-example-of-strict-content/2032796#2032796).